# checking two conditions simultaneously in a do-while loop

Tags: c++, do-while

In a tic-tac toe code, I had a do-while loop that checks if one of the players have won..so, something like this

```
do{
//does some player's input and other things..
}while(!win(x));
```

now, the big problem is in this loop, it will continue looping until one of the players win.
now, how do i check a tie using this same do-while loop?

could I do something like this :

```
do{
 //still the same checking
}while(!win(x)||!loose(x));
```

I did try this but it just messed up the code. How could I possibly check a tie in the game?

Thanks

Comment: Couldn't you refactor your code to have a `winOrDraw(x)` function?

Comment: Maybe you could have a `finished` flag, that is marked when someone wins or the grid is filled. Then have `while (!finished)`.

Comment: It's impossible to tell from this small snippet of code. It seems most logical to use `}while(gameIsNotOver());`...

Comment: can keep a count of maximum moves for both sides..... and checking that count of moves ..... for eg in 3*3 tic tac toe, maximum moves are 9.... so exit when max moves has been reached...

Comment: `... while (score(x) >= 0);`?

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is slightly off - change the loop condition from:

```
do{
 //still the same checking
}while(!win(x)||!loose(x));
```

to:

```
do{
 //still the same checking
}while(!win(x)&&!loose(x));
```

or perhaps a more easily understood, but equivalent alternative:

```
do{
 //still the same checking
}while(!(win(x)||loose(x)));
```

Comment: DeMorgan's Law will get you every time... basically you wanted to check for not ( `win(x) or lose(x)` ). But you forgot to negate all parts of the expression. The `or` goes to `and` (and vice versa). Just further clarifying what @Paul R suggested.

Comment: @willkill07: yes, good point - I've now added an alternate solution to the answer which illustrates de Morgan.

Comment: Amazing how the average human brain can't handle DeMorgan's laws.

Answer (score 0):

When you are writing:

```
!win(x)||!loose(x)
```

You say not won or not lost and the loop will terminate in the first go. You can use the following:

```
do{
    //still the same checking
} while (!win(x)&&!loose(x));
```

or

```
do{
    //still the same checking
} while (!(win(x)||loose(x)));
```